# How can I batch update specific apps?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I'm using a rooted Galaxy S5 with Lollipop. I want to update several apps over the Play store at once, but not all of them. Even if I have to use another app to do so, that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done using [AppBrain App Market](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appbrain-app-market/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps), an alternative frontend to the *Google Play Store*. This app a.o. lets you …

- exclude apps from updates permanently
- skip specific updates (and only be notified when the *next* update comes)

This way you can exclude stuff from the "batch update" and just have it performed for everything else. You still can update single apps manually. Hint: When using this app, you should disable update notifications from the *Google Play Store* app, or you'll get notified twice :)

If you like this approach and continue using *Appbrain*, a suggested additional install would be [AppBrain Ad Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appbrain-ad-detector/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector), which integrates here – so you know what to expect before you install an app :)